# Why fps is 30 in full screen mode in Overwatch

Tags: overwatch

If on windows mode, I got 60 fps

[image]

However, on full screen mode, I got only 30

[image]

It used to be 60 fps either way. I do not know why things changed.

Why?

Comment: What version of Windows (I'm assuming) are you running? What are your computer specs? Do you have an FPS limit set under 'options'?

Comment: It's fixed. Basically it happens since I change monitor. My monitor accept higher resolution even though it can only show lower resolution. Overwatch automatically try to show higher resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried solution here but fail.

https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20760796904

So I go to settings and pick borderless window.

There I saw that the resolution for overwatch is too high. It should be 1920 1080.

It seems that when I changed monitor, overwatch automatically uses high resolution thinking that my resolution is higher.

My monitor natural resolution is 1920 1080 but it can accept the higher resolution.

Overwatch try to show higher resolution which is, of course, useless.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/273323)

Comment: @TimS. Based on their comment this appears to be a fix. User4951, you should consider editing your answer to make it more clear if this solves your problem.

Comment: When I asked the question, I didn't know what's the problem. I found out about this problem afterward and want to tell others with similar problems. Overwatch change resolution without me knowing it. That's why DPS drop to 30. Simply manually changing the resolution helps.